# ASP.Net MVC Passing List<> to View with IEnumerable<>

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a simple contact list app.  I am using a view model that is totally separated from my domain model.  View has IEnumerable Here is my Index() Action Method to render the List:

```
private AddressBookContext db = new AddressBookContext();

public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<ContactListVM> viewListVM = new List<ContactListVM>();
    foreach (Contact c in db.Contacts.ToList())
    {
        viewListVM.Add(new ContactListVM
        {
            ContactID = c.ContactID,
            FirstName = c.FirstName,
            LastName  = c.LastName,
            Address1  = c.Address1,
            Address2  = c.Address2,
            City      = c.City,
            State     = c.State,
            ZipCode   = c.ZipCode,
            Phone     = c.Phone,
            Email     = c.Email,
            BirthDate = c.BirthDate         
        });
    }
    return View(viewListVM);
}
```

Is there a way to accomplish this with less code?

Answer (score 0):

[Automapper](http://automapper.org/) is a Nuget package that will help you cleanup your code. Specifically, it will remove the need to manually assign your domain properties to your viewmodel properties.

There is a little bit of setup involved, but the end result would look like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<ContactListVM> viewListVM = new List<ContactListVM>();
    foreach (Contact c in db.Contacts.ToList())
    {
        viewListVM.Add(Mapper.Map<Contact, ContactListVM>(c));
    }
    return View(viewListVM);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, using [AutoMapper](http://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper/3.1.1).

Once installed, start by creating a new mapping. You only need to do this once, I personally do it in `Application_Start`.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Contact, ContactListVM>();
```

Then it's as simple as mapping your query results to your desired output.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var contacts = db.Contacts.ToList();

    return View(Mapper.Map<List<ContactListVM>>(contacts));
}
```

And you're done, that simple.